# How can I enable international font support in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts

I'm running Firefox on Arch Linux, and my support for international fonts is very limited.

This results in a lot of tofu on web pages:

[image: Part of the Korean Wikipedia home page]

*Part of the [Korean Wikipedia home page](https://ko.wikipedia.org) as an example -- although most interational fonts show up the same way.*

Conversely, international fonts in the window's title bar do show up properly:

[image: The Firefox title bar when visiting Korean Wikipedia]

What I've tried so far is installing the a couple of the `firefox-18n-*` packages via `pacman`, and clearing my font cache using `fc-cache -f /usr/share/fonts`, but the issue's still around.

How can I get Firefox to render these international fonts properly?

Comment: Is the Firefox text encoding set to Unicode? Also, if you check the page source (Ctrl+U), can you see Hangul text? I presume Korean text display on other apps is OK (meaning system fonts are installed).

Comment: @user3169 Firefox _is_ set to Unicode, but manually setting it to Korean on ko.wikipedia.org (or Kannada, or Arabic, or any other encoding on its corresponding Wiki page) results in [this](http://i.imgur.com/5oULcsj.png). International characters show up properly in every other application on my system (gedit, vim, emacs, Thunderbird) except Chromium.

Comment: Why are you "manually setting it to Korean"? That doesn't work, even on my system. If you check the page source, you will see *charset="UTF-8"* so that (Unicode) is what FF must be set to. Other sites will depend on the encoding for those pages.

Comment: @user3169 `Why are you "manually setting it to Korean"?` Because it takes five seconds, is reversible, and because I've never had this issue before, IMO worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd actually figured this out a little while back by installing Google's [Noto fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/). I'm not at my Arch box right now, but under Fedora these are available in the repos as `google-noto-{sans,mono,serif}-fonts` for the lot of them.

Comment: you should also install Google Roboto fonts

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc that's totally a matter of preference and not necessarily relevant, unless Roboto has solid i18n support.

Comment: yes of course. It has been the default font in Android for years, and in my experience in many cases is better than Noto